# Bash regex for certain number length

Tags: regex, bash

So I'm trying to identify between 2 sets of numbers being entered as parameters into my script. One being a phone number and one being the limit for printing mongodb logs. The most simple way I can think of doing this is that if the number is more than 7 digits, it's most likely going to be a phone number as printing mongo results that lengthy is very unlikely.

I'm trying to put this into a case statement

```
case "$1" in

 regex here ) echo "not msisdn";;

 regex here ) echo "msisdn";;

 *) echo "not found";;

esac
```

I was thinking converting this to a string and checking the length would probably be easiest, as I can't seem to find any decent information on how to find the number of digits entered.

Edit: I should note that I was thinking of putting all this in an if statement, but these are not the only cases I will be checking, and I think the if statement will get very lengthy. The script I'm creating is already mostly ifs, so trying to change it up a bit. Let me know if I'm wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`case` doesn't support regular expressions; the wildcard syntax is a less capable formalism known as *glob* patterns <sup>1</sup>

```
case $1 in
  *[!0-9]*)
    echo "Not a number";;
  ? | ?? | ??? | ???? | ????? | ??????)
    echo "Six digits or less";;
  '')
    echo "Empty string";;
  *)
    echo "Seven digits or more";;
esac
```

It's not clear if non-numeric or empty inputs should be treated separately, but this shoud hopefully at least get you started.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some will argue that globs are a severely restricted form of regexe. I certainly disagree, because this is more confusing than helpful IMHO - several metacharacters have entirely different semantics, and what's left as similar is by and large the static parts and not the actually useful patterns.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! Didn't know about glob. Will look into more.

Answer (score 2):

`${#1}` contains the length of `$1`. So maybe just

```
if (( ${#1} > 7 )) ; then
    echo Phone number
else
    echo Too short for a phone number
fi
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking of doing originally, but I'm still learning bash and my script already has a ton of ifs. Wanted to change it up a bit. I'll be having multiple other params and I wanted them to be interchangeable so they could be input in any order or left out if not needed. I think an using ifs would make this really messy.